# odd bug involving blockquote button?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Over on the main site, start typing an answer, hit the blockquote button, the following appears:

function (){if(typeof this[0]=="undefined"){return 0}var c=this[0].length;var b=this.length;for(var a=1;ac){c=this[a].length}}return c}

This happens using chrome 12/Ubuntu 11 at home, and firefox 3.6.1/windows xp at work.

Comment: Repro'd using Chrome 13.0.782.32 beta-m and Firefox 5.0 on Windows XP.  Very interesting.  It seemed to work normally when there was no text in the answer, but inserted the javascript when there was text.  Couldn't repro on IE8, and it's not happening here on Meta or other sites (checked Gaming and Android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue caused by the fact that jTab (the guitar chord displaying thing) messes around with the `Array` prototype, and we – against good practice – had a `for...in` loop that failed to check for `hasOwnProperty` (or, well, use indexing in the first place).

Fixed after the next build; thanks!